# Storing multiple API responses?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

so not too sure what the best way to handle this is. But essentially I have a dictionary that contains query syntax values that I feed into a function that queries an API:

Simple example:

```
for item in dict:
    function(item['query'])
```

If I have 5 items in the dictionary, I will get back 5 different responses. I would like to store these responses independently - and not aggregate them (I want to do some parsing/selection of the responses that will be different for each one). Should I just create 5 different empty lists and feed the responses to them? e.g. responseList1 = [], responseList2 = [] etc.

I think that would work in my case, but I feel like there is a better approach - especially in a scenario where you might have 500 items in the dictionary -> 500 different responses.

Comment: why don't you store all the 5 responses in single list? what is the issue in storing them in same list?also show sample response

Comment: Hmm, could I just append that? The response is json/jsonl - basically multiple json objects newline delimited for each query (5 in my example). Also thank you for the reply!

Comment: still i didn't see any issue in storing in the same list?

Comment: How would that syntax look?